# Sony Qx1 API getEvent incomplete

Tags: camera, sony

The QX1 is able to do exposure compensation. According to the getEvent API reference page 234, it should be in item 25. This item is empty. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Which exposure mode are you in when you get the empty item?  If the exposure mode is set to something like "Intelligent Auto" then the item will be empty since exposure compensation is not supported in that mode.  Try setting it to a manual mode and see if the item is returned.